# AJAX POST to PHP mySQL query

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am getting the proper log in the console but it isn't going to the database I cannot see anything wrong with my PHP, though. Can anyone see what might be the problem?

JQuery code:

```
 $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      height: 300,
      width: 350,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Create an account": function() {

        var fname = $( "#guestfname" ).val();
        var lname = $( "#guestlname" ).val();
        var gender = $( "#guestgender" ).val();
        var address = $( "#guestaddress" ).val();
        var city = $( "#guestcity" ).val();
        var state = $( "#gueststate" ).val();
        var zip = $( "#guestzip" ).val();
        var phone = $( "#guestphone" ).val();
        var email = $( "#guestemail" ).val();
        var dob = $( "#guestdob" ).val();

        var dataString ={fname:fname, lname:lname, gender:gender, address:address,
                            city:city, state:state, zip:zip, phone:phone, email:email,
                            dob:dob};
        console.log(dataString);    
            $.ajax({        
                type: "POST",
                url: "classes/add_guest.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html)
                {
                    $('.guestinfo').html(html);
                }
            });
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
        Cancel: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      },
      close: function() {
      }
    });

    $( "#create-user" )
      .button()
      .click(function() {
        $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
      });
  });
```

PHP mySQL query code:

```
<?php
//open connection
require_once('../config/db.php');
$con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

//get date
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname =  $_POST['lname'];
$gender = $_POST['gender'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$state = $_POST['state'];
$zip = $_POST['zip'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$dob = $_POST['dob'];


mysqli_query($con, 'INSERT INTO guests(fname, lname, gender, address, city, state, zip, phone, email, dob)
                    VALUES("'.$fname.'","'.$lname.'","'.$gender.'","'.$address.'","'.$city.'","'.$state.'",'.
                    $zip.','.$phone.',"'.$email.'",'.$dob.'');

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a slight problem, string must be single quoted before passed to MySQL server:

```
mysqli_query($con, 'INSERT INTO guests(fname, lname, gender, address, city, state, zip, phone, email, dob)
                VALUES("'.$fname.'","'.$lname.'","'.$gender.'","'.$address.'","'.$city.'","'.$state.'",'.
                $zip.','.$phone.',"'.$email.'",'.$dob.'');
```

=> Good syntax here:

```
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO guests(fname, lname, gender, address, city,
  state, zip, phone, email, dob)
VALUES('$fname', '$lname', '$gender', '$address', '$city',
  '$state', '$zip', '$phone', '$email', '$dob'");
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your query string doesn't need to be added together, PHP can pick out which are variables. So try this

```
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO guests (fname, lname, gender, address, city, state, zip, phone, email, dob) VALUES ('$fname','$lname','$gender','$address','$city','$state','zip','$phone','$email','$dob')";
```

If that doesn't work add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the top of your page try changing all your `$_POST`'s to `$_REQUEST`'s. Then go to the page with the variables in the URL (GET Method).  That should tell you the error. For example `website.com/add_guest.php?lname=Dave`

Answer (score 1):

First off, you're not escaping anything. Or using prepared statements. Hello, [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) (or SQL injection if you like).

Second, you're not wrapping your values in your statements in quotes. For instance, `$phone` isn't wrapped. I don't think MySQL would take too kindly to

```
INSERT INTO table(phone) VALUES(123-867-5309)
```

So we need to quote all your strings

```
INSERT INTO table(phone) VALUES("123-867-5309")
```

Third, What's going on with your AJAX? Did you use something like Firebug to make sure your AJAX was being sent properly? And have you ever heard of [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)? MUCH easier way to post your form data.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help all. We all missed it, though. `mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO guests(fname, lname, gender, address, city,
    state, zip, phone, email, dob)
    VALUES('$fname', '$lname', '$gender', '$address', '$city',
    '$state', '$zip', '$phone', '$email', '$dob')");`

Forgot that `)` to close the `VALUES`.